# How to suppress images when browsing?

Tags: images, browser, plugins

I would like to read newspapers online without displaying images. Is it possible?
Maybe using a plugin for my browser (Chrome)? Maybe using a different browser?

I would like to have that as an option. Sometimes I want to turn images on again.
Since some images are embedded in Flash, I would like to be able to disable Flash too.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Options > Under the Hood > Images > Do not show any images`

You can then add exceptions for other sites. (Under the hood as another name in US English I guess).

Comment: `Under the bonnet`, if you've switched to En-UK